# How do I display wordpress admin bar outside wordpress?

Tags: admin-bar

Let's say that I have a URL path that is not handled by wordpress,like `/custom/` but I want to add the admin bar to these pages.

What should I add to these pages in order to make the admin bar available in them.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-includes/js/admin-bar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

wp_admin_bar_render();
?>
</body>
</html>
```